# Excel VBA - Worksheet public member not available

Tags: excel, vba

System: Excel 2013; Windows 7 Pro x64

I am having a strange issue with accessing public members of a worksheet in vba code.

Here is minimum code to duplicate.

**Sheet1 (General) vba code**

```
Public memberVar As Integer
```

**MyModule vba code**

```
Sub MySub()
  MySub2 Sheet1
End Sub

Sub MySub2(sht As Worksheet)
  Dim foo As Integer
  foo = 1
  sht.memberVar = foo
End Sub
```

When I run `MySub` from the Immediate window, I get the following error:
"Compile Error: Method or data member not found" on the third line in MySub2, where it references `sht.memberVar`

The strange part to me is that if I comment out the line `sht.memberVar = foo` and set a breakpoint at `foo = 1` and inspect `sht` in the locals window, `memberVar` is indeed listed as a member of the object.

So what gives? Am I going about this wrong? It appears that if I change declaration to `MySub2(sht As Object)` then I don't get errors, but this seems like a hack because I already know exactly what type the object should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sht` is typed as "the generic, non-specific" Worksheet. However, `Sheet1` is a "special" Worksheet, which has a property called `memberVar`. The fact that `sht` will be run with `Sheet1` will only be known during runtime, i.e. dynamically. You could best visualize this, by assuming that there was another sub around, which was defined like this:

```
Sub UglySub()
  MySub2 Sheet2
End Sub
```

When starting the code, you are compiling the VBA script - and there you claim that there was a property `memberVar` at "the generic, non-specific" Worksheet - which does not hold true. Hence the error message when compiling/starting your code.

When you comment the assignment out and modify the type to `Object` (which is not necessary, as Worksheet would be equally good), you are passing over from the static designtime to the runtime. The compiler is through and you are then observing the runtime situation.

IIRC, Worksheets are not just global identifiers for variables, but can also be used in type positions. So

```
Sub MySub2(sht As Sheet1)
  Dim foo As Integer
  foo = 1
  sht.memberVar = foo
End Sub
```

might already be enough to do the trick to keep the compiler's mouth shut.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. This trick of using a specific worksheet as the type does indeed work. Thanks!